# Why doesn't [Required] work for me? MVC3

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple model with a property like below.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "User name is Required")]    
    [Display(Name = "User name")]   
    public virtual string Inserted_By
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


  public virtual int FK_ClientID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

My view looks like so.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Booking</legend>


       <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Inserted_By)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Inserted_By)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Inserted_By)
    </div>

           <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_ClientID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_ClientID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_ClientID)
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

If I try to enter text into the FK_ClientID field I get "The field FK_ClientID must be a number" which is correct.  However if I enter nothing into the Inserted_By textbox it doesn't validate??